# ODBC Driver not found "File not found error"

Tags: database, odbc, clickhouse

I am trying to connect to the database but getting error `file not found`, the same error is with `isql`. I know the file is there with correct permission.

```
$ isql -v ClickHouse
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib64/libclickhouseodbc.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

$ ls -lrt /usr/lib64/libclickhouseodbc.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 33920808 Mar  7 14:32 /usr/lib64/libclickhouseodbc.so

$ ldd /usr/lib64/libclickhouseodbc.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffbf36d000)
        libodbc.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libodbc.so.2 (0x00007f2366d2f000)
        libm.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2366a2c000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f236665f000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000558044ea1000)
        libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib64/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f2366455000)
        libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2366250000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2366034000)

$ which isql | xargs file
/bin/isql: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=dacf3a0f9b65968e63f2ca5b0f79b522f5d7e567, stripped

$ which isql | xargs ldd
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd45fef000)
        libodbc.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libodbc.so.2 (0x00007fe706ad3000)
        libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib64/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007fe7068c8000)
        libreadline.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007fe706682000)
        libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe70647e000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe706261000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe705e94000)
        libtinfo.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007fe705c6a000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005638f62f2000)


$ file /usr/lib64/libclickhouseodbc.so 
/usr/lib64/libclickhouseodbc.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=aac633748dcbd6d9bf228372c6dbc524e751c4d0, not stripped
```

Comment: I have removed the tag [tag:c] since this question doesn't appear to be about C.

Comment: Is everything in this stack 64-bit? Sometimes bitness mismatches result in a misleading "file not found" error. Check `file /usr/lib64/libclickhouseodbc`, `which isql | xargs file`, `which isql | xargs ldd`.

Comment: @TallTed I have pasted the information but all are 64bits.

Comment: What OS? Where did you get libclickhouseodbc? Download somewhere / build by your own?

Comment: I bet something is wrong with build, i see it's dynamically linked, while original build creates statically linked library. So may be it was linked on another machine with another version of libs?